# Error convert findByID to @BindView when upgrading ButterKnife

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, replace, butterknife

I have a project from someone else, but when I opened it there was some error. Butterknife has an error, it displays: "`error: can't find findById (View, int) notation`", I know that it has been replaced by @BindView, I changed `findById` to `@BindView` but only findById 2 parameters while `@BindView` only has 1. How do I convert it?

This is new code:

```
@BindView(R.id.fab_subitem_image) ImageView image;
private void addActionItem(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, int index,
    @NonNull final FABAction item) {
    // Inflate & Configure item
    final View subItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_subitem, mItemContainer, false);

    image.setBackgroundColor(item.mBgColor);
```

This is old code:

```
private void addActionItem(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, int index,
    @NonNull final FABAction item) {
    // Inflate & Configure item
    final View subItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_subitem, mItemContainer, false);
    ImageView image = ButterKnife.findById(subItem, R.id.fab_subitem_image); <--This is old code

    image.setBackgroundColor(item.mBgColor);
```

Comment: did you add `ButterKnife.bind(this); or  ButterKnife.bind(this, subItem);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell ButterKnife to generate bindings for the object that contains `@BindView` annotations. You should call `ButterKnife.bind(this, subItem)` after inflation:

```
@BindView(R.id.fab_subitem_image) ImageView image;

private Unbinder unbinder;

private void addActionItem(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, int index, @NonNull final FABAction item) {
    // Inflate & Configure item
    final View subItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_subitem, mItemContainer, false);
    // Generate bindings
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, subItem);

    image.setBackgroundColor(item.mBgColor);
    ...
}

...

@Override
public void onDestroyView(View view) {
    // Unbind when bindings are no longer needed eg. in onDestroyView of a Fragment
    unbinder.unbind()
}
```

See [the documentation](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for more information.